# Cosmos DB Substring query example

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I've a document like this in db

```json
{
   "startDate": "2023-11-17T08:11:30.225323"
}
```

When querying I can say

```sql
select *
from c.startDate = "2023-11-17T08:11:30.225323"
```

which is working. But I need to query only with `date part` so I did something like this `select SUBSTRING(c.effectiveDate,0,10)` which is giving me results because my input to the query will be like this `2023-11-17`.

So from query side it's all working but I'm trying to build this query using java cosmos sdk. For this I'm using something called Criteria from `com.azure.spring.data.cosmos.core.query.Criteria` package. For example for the above query I use something like this

```
Criteria c1 = Criteria.getInstance(CriteriaType.IS_EQUAL, "startDate", Collections.singletonList(startDate), Part.IgnoreCaseType.NEVER);
```

Now using the same `Criteria` how do I achieve `SUBSTRING` functionality.

Comment: Not quite sure about your query - it's not valid sql (I think you're missing a bit after the `from`). As for building your query - can't you just pass your query, as written? Also: be mindful of performance impact using `SUBSTRING()` if you're processing a lot of data (might be better to trim the resulting string after it's returned, vs executing a function on hundreds or thousands of strings)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion basically I need to query `startDate="2023-11-17"` whereas startDate is saved as `2023-11-17T08:11:30.225323`. How can I achieve this using `Criteria` @DavidMakogon

Comment: Query the datetime like it's a datetime. If you are only interested in the date part you can filter between the start of the day and end of the day. Which will also be a lot more optimized as it'll be able to leverage the index using a precise index scan.